# Deleting Workbook_open() code with button click before save

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I have a workbook that I am using to generate purchase orders.
In ThisWorkbook I have the below code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
Sheet1.[g6] = Sheet1.[g6] + 1
Sheet1.[b4] = ""
Sheet1.[c10] = ""
Sheet1.[a17] = ""
Sheet1.[a20:h35] = ""
Sheet1.CommandButton2.Enabled = False
Sheet1.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I also have the attached code on Sheet1. Is there a way to delete the Workbook_open coding in the commandbutton2_click()? The workbook is emailed and saved appropriately, however everytime it is re-opened it repeats the workbook_open() and clears out the data. The saved workbook still needs to have Macro's enabled, because of an approval process.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("B4")) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill Highlighted cells before closing."
        Cancel = True
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("C10")) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill Highlighted cells before closing."
        Cancel = True
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A17")) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill Highlighted cells before closing."
        Cancel = True
    End If


Dim FileName As String
 Dim Path As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Path = "\\COSRVR1\Data\Purchase orders\"
 FileName = Sheet1.Range("G6").Value & ".xlsm"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

CommandButton2.Visible = False

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olmail.To = Sheet1.Range("a8")
olmail.Subject = "Approval needed_" & Sheet1.Range("g6")
olmail.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
olmail.send
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sheet1.Range("i38").Value > 1999 Then
        CommandButton2.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton2.Enabled = False
End If
    If Sheet1.Range("i38").Value = 0 Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    Else
    End If
    If Sheet1.Range("i38").Value < 2000 Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630035/how-to-clear-the-vba-code-of-a-worksheet-via-a-macro).  It will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
End With
```